# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier - with SCRIPT DECLARATION

Tags: javascript

has anyone met this problem? this shows directly on the script declaration..

[image]

Comment: Can you post more than the first three lines, because I don't believe that you forgot to close the division tags or the script tag and simply didn't include it in the screenshot.

Comment: answer was posted, problem found..

Answer (score -2):

The problem was in declaration of one of the lines. I dont know why debugger doesnt shows that line directly..

[image]